# Function Issue: Date filter in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, function, date

So, I'm having an issue with making a function that just returns 1 if the date is set in a quarter previous to the actual one. I'm not fluent with functions, so it might be a stupid mistake, but I can't fix it. Thank you kind souls:)

```
Public Function IsOnQX(ByVal InputCell As Range, ByVal Month As Long) As Integer
    Dim ActualQuarter As String
    Dim PastQuarter As String

        If (Month < 1) Or (Month > 12) Then
                Call Err.Raise(6) ' Value out of Bounds '
        End If

        Set ActualQuarter = ((Month(Now())) + 2) \ 3
        Set PastQuarter = ((Month(InputCell.Value)) + 2) / 3

        If (InputCell.Value = "") Or (PastQuarter < ActualQuarter) Then
            IsOnQX = 1
        Else
            IsOnQX = 0
        End If

End Function
```

My idea is to use this function as part of a COUNTIFS statement in a Macro that returns the number of items that comply with two conditions: either the cell in the table is empty (returns 1) or the date contained in said cell is from a previous quarter period (=1) again, and just count the 1s to get the total amount.

Something like;

```
Range("C63")=COUNTIFS(TablaI_R[Project Name], IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(TablaI_R[Project Name],AZAR),1,0)=1), TablaI_R[Actual Closed Date], IF(IsOnQX(TablaI_R[Actual Closed Date])=1, 1, 0)=1)
```

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Edit: Updated to return a `1` for a blank cell***

Given a date, you can do this with a one-liner:

```
Function inPrevQx(D As Date) As Long
    inPrevQx = IIf(Abs(DateDiff("m", D, Date)) > 6 And CLng(D) <> 0, 0, Abs(DatePart("q", DateAdd("q", 1, D)) = DatePart("q", DateAdd("q", 0, Date)) Or CLng(D) = 0))
End Function
```

[image]

By examining the formula, and using VBA help to understand the functions, you should be able to figure out the algorithm. Ask if you have any questions.

**Edit 2**

OP has clarified that he wants a `0` returned for the current quarter, and a `1` returned for any other quarter (or blanks, I assume).

That being the case, the above can be modified to:

**Edit 3** *(further simplification)*

```
Function notInCurrQx(D As Date)
  notInCurrQx = Abs(DateDiff("q", D, Date) <> 0)
  'or even:  notInCurrQx = -(DateDiff("q", D, Date) <> 0)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! I don't really understand why the `Abs(DateDiff("m", D, Date)) > 6` is there, I rephrased the Function as:

`inPrevQx = IIf(Abs(DateDiff("q", D, Date)) > 1 And CLng(D) <> 0, 1, Abs(DatePart("q", DateAdd("q", 1, D)) = DatePart("q", DateAdd("q", 0, Date)) Or CLng(D) = 0))`

and now works wonders. You made my day, kind stranger. Thank you so much.
Edits: I'm not used to not being able to hit "enter" haha.

Comment: @wiser Set up a column of dates at monthly intervals from `1-Jan-2019` to `12/1/2020`. Your function returns `0` for the current quarter and the 1st quarter of 2020, and `1` for  dates in every other quarter.  Mine returns a `1` for just the previous quarter (July-Sep 2019), which is what I thought you wanted.

Comment: Oh, I was trying to get a function that returned 1 if it was in any previous (or future, but that should not happen) quarter, and 0 if in the current quarter. English isn't my first language, and clearly, neither is VBA haha. I'll see wwhy the following quarter also returns 0

Comment: @wiser Further simplicfication:  See **Edit 3**

Comment: Hey! Thank you so much! You've been very helpful

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't declare `String` variables when doing simple arithmetic.
Also `Set` is used for `Object` type variables.

You could use `Let` for other variables, but that isn't needed in *modern* Visual Basic.

```
Public Function IsOnQX(ByVal InputCell As Range, ByVal Month As Long) As Integer
    Dim ActualQuarter As Integer
    Dim PastQuarter As Integer
    If (Month < 1) Or (Month > 12) Then
            Call Err.Raise(6) ' Value out of Bounds '
    End If

    ActualQuarter = (Month(Date) + 2) \ 3
    PastQuarter = (Month(InputCell.Value) + 2) \ 3
    If IsEmpty(InputCell) Or (PastQuarter < ActualQuarter) Then
        IsOnQX = 1
    Else
        IsOnQX = 0
    End If
End Function
```